# disable-background-timer-throttling & pause-background-tabs flag is not working as expected in Chrome version 64

Tags: google-chrome, timer, throttling

My application has background threads running, but because of optimization is done in Chrome by default, those threads are throttled when the browser is minimized or running in the inactive tab. We have flags to disable the throttling done by Chrome. 
I have disabled these 2 flags in Chrome
--pause-background-tabs -> disabled
--disable-background-timer-throttling -> disabled

But still, I could see the throttling is still happening in inactive tabs/minimized browser of chrome, any idea how to disable?