# Disable in Chrome: Active Resource Loading Per-Frame Limit

Tags: google-chrome

I'm getting this console notice in Chrome Devtools while developing on localhost:

> Active resource loading counts reached a per-frame limit while the tab
>   was in background. Network requests will be delayed until a previous
>   loading finishes, or the tab is brought to the foreground. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5527160148197376 for more details

I tried disabling the "Throttle expensive background timers" flag [here](http://chrome://flags/#expensive-background-timer-throttling) but that didn't work. The link provided in the console message doesn't say how to disable/override.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48946692/723007) might be asking the same thing but I'm not certain.

Does anyone know how to override this setting in Chrome? I'm running Chrome Canary 72.x on Mac.

Answer (score 9):

Via the Chrome team, set Enable Resource Load Throttling to disabled:

`chrome://flags/#enable-resource-load-scheduler`

Comment: Does it work for you? Because it did not work out for me

Comment: It seemed to worked for a short time but then started up again. I reported it [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=723233) but replicating/isolating it well enough to be helpful to the issue owners is difficult. Other developers have started reporting similar issues, so hopefully it will be resolved soon. As a temporary workaround, I'm running a Bash script in the watch task that momentarily focuses Canary. I can provide more info about this if you want but it's a complete hack.

Comment: I could image he is complaining about that link you gave. Ensure you use this url in `chrome`: `chrome://flags/#enable-resource-load-scheduler` because of the missing colon…